# Kernel of a linear function...

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider the real vector spaces $R^4$ and $R^5$, and linear function:

$f: (a, b, c, d, e) ∈ R^5 → (a - d, a - d, e - d, c) ∈ R^4$.

• Find the kernel of $f$, its base and its dimension.

• Find the image of $f$, its base and its dimension.

My attempt to find the ker:

I made a system with $a - d, a - d, e - d, c$ and all the possible solutions are $(0,0,0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0,1,1)$, $(0,1,0,0,0)$, $(1,1,0,1,1)$...

Comment: Well, the kernel will be infinite (it includes the points $(a,0,0,a,a)$ for example) so listing them all isn't going to work.

Comment: @lulu *nucleus.

Comment: Use the canonical basis and write down the matrix corresponding to that linear map and then analyze the matrix.

Comment: @21säv I didn't understand.